# Why are "UFO Aliens" always naked?

Tags: aliens, history-of

It seems to me that all aliens that come from UFOs (i.e. the Area 51 alien with a big head and slender body) don't wear clothes.

Why is that?

Comment: Well, if they made it Area 51, I am sure they have been... uh... *studied*...

Comment: I always heard they were in metalic colored suits that looked like spandex.  Perhaps they just look naked because their idea of clothing is substantially unlike our "pelts of animals" or "leaves of trees"?

Comment: I think the idea is that they don't need clothes, so they don't wear them.  The type fo alien you're referring to are typically known as "greys." Greys aren't *always* depicted as being naked, but they are often so.  *When* they're naked, they're usually also depicted without (visible) gender, therefore they don't need clothes for modesty.  They also don't need clothes for comfort - they've mastered interstellar travel, it's probably safe to assume they've got AC licked.

Comment: I'm sure an alien visiting earth would wonder why we _do_ wear clothes. It is a pretty strange behaviour.